# Discord bot crashes when message contain mention

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
undefined:1
(@!310599774002872330)
 ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Commands work fine but whenever it involves a mention/ping it crashes the bot and spits out the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was because i made an eval command that looks for content within <>, and so it thought the mention was one of those.